# How can I let something happen a certain percentage of the time? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm a noob at javascript, sorry if this is a dumb question.
I want something to happen a certain % of the time.

So if a user clicks a button, x% of the time situation A will happen (Let's call this succes) and the other times situation B will happen.

The thing is, that the more user succeeds, the more % chance the user should have of succeeding the next time.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: Without any specific code from your side, it is almost impossible to help you here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, I know about math.random - I just don't undestand how I should use it in this situation.

Comment: `var p = 0.1; if (Math.random() > p) { /* Action B */ } else { p += 0.1; /* Action A */ }`

Comment: @jaspere Well, engage the brain. Math.random gives you a random number between 0 and 1. If you want a 75% chance, what number do you put in your `if()` statement?

Comment: @le_m ah, I'm so stupid.
thanks man.

Comment: @jaspere next time just leave out the "I am a noob" and ask "What is the best / fastest / most elegant way to accomplish X" and nobody will bat an eye answering your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a viable solution. The user starts with an extra bonus of 0, the more he succeeds the higher chance of success later on. Each time the button is pressed a random number is generated between 0 and 1, and you see if that number plus the `bonus` is greater than some number (.9 in my example).

```js
var bonus=0.0;

$("#percentage").on("click",function(){
  var r=Math.random();
  if(r+bonus>.9){
   $("#succeed").text("Success");
    bonus+=.05
  }else{
   $("#succeed").text("Failure");
    }
   var p=Math.round(bonus*100);
  $("#chance").text((p<100?p:100)+"%+");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=button Value="Click Me" id="percentage">
<div id="succeed">
</div>
<div id="chance">
</div>
```

Comment: perfect, thanks.
I understand now. :)